# cohomology ring of mapping spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, mapping-class-groups, loop-spaces, mapping-space

In the lecture notes [The homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$–spaces, n ≥ 0. F. Cohen, 1978,](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf) page 228-231, the cohomology ring 
$$
H^*(\text{Map}_*(S^n, S^n\wedge X);\mathbb{Z}_p)
$$
is obtained for any primes $p\geq 2$.

**Question:** I want to know the cohomology ring 
$$
H^*(\text{Map}_*(M, S^n);\mathbb{Z}_2)
$$
for some manifolds $M$ other than $S^n$, for example, $M=\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}P^n, \mathbb{C}P^n, \mathbb{T}^n, S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}, $ etc. Are there any such generalizations or references? Thanks.

I also do not understand the proof in [The homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$–spaces, n ≥ 0. F. Cohen, 1978,](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf) page 228-231, the part proving $H_*\Omega^{n+1}_\phi\Sigma^{n+1}X=AT_nH_*X$ ($\Omega^{n+1}_\phi\Sigma^{n+1}X$ denotes the path-component of $\Omega^{n+1}\Sigma^{n+1}X$ containing the base-point, i.e., the collection of maps in Map$_*(S^{n+1},S^{n+1}\wedge X)$ of degree $0$). Could you explain it more? Thanks!

Comment: I'll just list some basics. Since the mapping space is only dependent on the based homotopy class of $M$, $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial. For $M=S^{1}\times \mathbb{R}$, then $Map_*(S^1, S^n)=\Omega S^n$, so the cohomology is $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ in degrees divisible by $n$, and $0$ otherwise. The case of higher tori gets extremely complicated, see [here](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mypapers/loop.pdf), but the Serre spectral sequence associated to $Map(\mathbb{T}^{m}, S^n)\to *\to Map(\mathbb{T}^{m-1}, S^n)$ can, for example, that for $m=2$ and $n=2s+1$, it is a polynomial ring.